# Override Magento_Ui base view template file on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, ui-form, theme-overriding

In Magento, we can override vendor's file

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/input.html

like:

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Ui/web/templates/form/element/input.html

**- Above file is used for frontend.**

But I want to override vendor base template file of

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/form/element/input.html

**- This file is used for Admin/Backend(adminhtml).**

How can i override base file in theme folder ?

Does anyone know its solution?

Comment: Themes are area specific. Changes made in a frontend them won't apply in the admin area. You need an admin theme

Comment: @vitoriodachef Thanks for instant reply. does it possible without admin theme?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm do not know any other way.

Comment: If the template is used for UiComponents only, and a specific one, technically you could change the UiComponent definition so the field component (for e.g.) will use your template and not the default one.